# How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas based on list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, contains

Supposed I have a dataframe with one column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(100, 1)), columns=['number'])
```

I have two lists, one list containing even numbers, the other containing odd numbers.

```
odd_numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
even_numbers = [0,2,4,6,8]
```

I'd like to create another series on the dataframe that says 'even' or 'odd' depending on the value within df['number']

Something like:

```
df['odd_or_even'] = 'even' if df[number].isin(even_numbers)
df['odd_or_even'] = 'odd' if df[number].isin(odd_numbers)
```

Comment: It's important that the list is the conditional check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(100, 1)), columns=['number'])

df['odd_or_even'] = np.where(df.number % 2, 'odd', 'even')
print (df)

    number odd_or_even
0        1         odd
1        0        even
2        4        even
3        5         odd
4        0        even
5        0        even
6        1         odd
7        0        even
8        7         odd
9        8        even
```

EDIT by comment

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(20, 1)), columns=['number'])

odd_numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
even_numbers = [0,2,4,6,8]

df.loc[df.number.isin(odd_numbers), 'odd_or_even'] = 'odd'
df.loc[df.number.isin(even_numbers), 'odd_or_even'] = 'even'

print (df)
    number odd_or_even
0        5         odd
1        1         odd
2        2        even
3        3         odd
4        5         odd
5        6        even
6        3         odd
7        4        even
8        2        even
9        8        even
10       8        even
11       1         odd
12       2        even
13       1         odd
14       3         odd
15       3         odd
16       5         odd
17       4        even
18       2        even
19       5         odd
```

Comment: I've simplified my dataframe for this example. I'm not actually checking for odd or even numbers. I need to check an existing series' elements against a list.

Answer (score 1):

A [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) version:

First, create a dictionary:

```
d = {**{o: "odd" for o in odd_numbers}, **{e: "even" for e in even_numbers}}
```

Then use map on the series:

```
df['odd_or_even'] = df['number'].map(d)
```